# In postgres how to find the shortest string an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find the shortest string in postgres.  Searched around could not find any answers. My use case started from a aggregate function in SQL:

```
select key_col, strarr_shortest(text_col) as text_col
from (
    select key_col, array_agg(tex_col::text) as text_col
    from mytable group by key_col
) foo;
```

It turn out I have to write a pl/pgsql to solve this problem.

Comment: Does the inner part of the query be like that (e.g. because you cannot control that) are can the whole query be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to aggregate the rows and search in arrays. Use `distinct on`, example:

```
with mytable (key_col, text_col) as (
values 
    (1, 'asd'), 
    (1, 'a'),   
    (2, 'asd'), 
    (2, 'asdfg')    
)

select distinct on (key_col) key_col, text_col as shortest
from mytable
order by key_col, length(text_col)

 key_col | shortest 
---------+----------
       1 | a
       2 | asd
(2 rows)
```

If you really need the function (to use in other circumstances), it may be a simple query wrapped in an SQL function:

```
create or replace function shortest(text[])
returns text language sql as $$
    select elem
    from unnest($1) as elem
    order by length(elem)
    limit 1;
$$;
```

Comment: No need to add a function is a plus for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a new function; not sure this is the best answer or not. There might be solution in pure SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strarr_shortest(arr text[]) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
   res text;
   minlen int := 2147483647;  -- largest singed int in postgres
   el text;
BEGIN
   FOREACH el IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
        if char_length(el) < minlen then
            res=el;
            minlen=char_length(el);
        end if;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN res;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```